# JAVAFX Style textArea for chat application with bubble

Tags: javafx

I'm making chat application with JAVAFX, and I want the chat messages to be displayed in bubbles. can someone explain to me how can it be done?
I know I need to use in 3 images for the bubble - for the top, bottom, and for the middle, that depend on how many rows the message will be. but this is all theory. I have no clue how to implement it on a textArea in JAVAFX.
So I'll be grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how wide your bubbles are going to be and the size of the font, you can do some logic to determine how many lines there will be because you will know how many characters will fit on one line. For example, if the line holds 10 characters (for ease of math; I'm sure it's more) then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String in = new String("blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah");
    System.out.println("length is " + in.length());
    int charCount = in.length();
    int allowedCharsOnLine = 10;
    int extraChars = charCount - (allowedCharsOnLine*2);
    System.out.println("extra chars is " + extraChars);
    int numberOfMiddleSections = (extraChars)/allowedCharsOnLine;
    System.out.println("You need " + numberOfMiddleSections + " middle sections");
}
```

Drop that in a java class and run it to see what I'm talking about. The String in would come from your user input of course. And you would want to make the allowedCharsOnLine a final class level variable probably, but I just put it in there for ease of reading.